# Posting data into MySQL without form tag

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, intrexx

I'm using Intrexx Professional to build some forms for my company. These forms are not built with code.

However, they support JavaScript, JQuery and AJAX for extra functionality.

I was just wondering if you could provide information on how to save the form data into MySQL with jQuery and AJAX. I was looking at some tutorials, but they are all based on HTML forms. Thanks

Comment: Google it, imagine if we'd receive 100.000 questions per day with the same question, 100 is more than enough..

Comment: Everyone starts from somewhere... I searched for it, but I couldn't find something for my purpose. But I got the point now. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get values of inputs using jquery,

```
var a = $('#id-of-a').val(); 
var b = $('#id-of-b').val(); //and so on.
```

instead of `.serialize()`. Or you can use an array for variables, and loop using .each() or other methods in jquery to get values.

Post to php file and get response,

```
$.post(
   "http://www.example.com/ajax.php",
   { a : a, b : b},  //variables.
   function(response){
        //process response
        console.log(response);
});
```

You may also use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to post to php.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do I need a PHP with some sql queries as well or the above sufficient?

Comment: Of course you need a php file that will process these information sent on server side and generate the response. You need to read documentation of ajax to get a better understanding.

Comment: Ok Optimus! Thanks for the advice. I'll accept your answer as well. Cheers